Distributing SDK as Binaries Using Swift Package

I have created the xcframework.zip of my current SDK using Github Action for iOS and iOS Simulator.
My current SDK has three external dependencies.
My current SDK has public classes and methods that are supposed to be accessed by the clients.
I am trying to distribute it through Swift Package using binaryTarget, but no matter what I do, I am not able to access the public classes and methods.
I tried directly accessing xcframework without Swift Package and it still doesn't expose any public code.

I know I am providing minimum details here, but please feel free to reach out if you need more details.
